# Method for Perl to Communicate with C# & ASP to get response back to Perl

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, perl

I have a .NET application with an ASP webpage that is using C# to do the server side processing and dynamically controlled webpage. The portion the question is focused on is a form being submitted. The submitted form is then handed off to a Perl script to process. There are cases though when there is a conflict that requires the user to view and either confirm or cancel the process. So, the Perl script would need to talk back to the C# class, to give a prompt to the user through the webpage to verify the data and confirm, which would then have the C# send the confirmation to the Perl script to continue on.

As of right now, the project can call the Perl script and upon completion, it returns a response which is displayed to the user. I would like the ability to communicate periodically back to the user on the webpage through the run of the Perl script. Is this possible?

I've looked into the Win32::API, but I am not sure if this is the correct route to take.

Here is how I am currently calling the Perl script from C#:

```
ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe");
perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\usr\bin\perl.exe");
perlStartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + webAppPath + "ccrmiddleman.pl\" -action submit -date " + Date1.Text;
perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
perlStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process perl = new Process();
perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;
perl.Start();
StdOut.Text = perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
StdErr.Text = perl.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
perl.WaitForExit(60);enter code here
```

When the web form is submitted and after this Perl script is executed, it then sends the response back asynchronously to the webpage to launch a lightbox window.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"><!--div-->
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelDate1" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="ClearBtn" runat="server" Text="Clear" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return CleanForm();" />

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Date1Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Date1" ValidationExpression="\d\d/\d\d/\d\d" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid date."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" CssClass="input" runat="server" TargetControlID="Date1" TodaysDateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy" Format="MM/dd/yy" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="callserver"></asp:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="DateFilter" runat="server" TargetControlID="Date1" FilterType="Custom, Numbers" ValidChars="/" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="light" class="white_content"><asp:Label ID="lbText" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br /><br /><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

            <DBWC:DynamicControlsPlaceholder ID="PlaceHolder" runat="server" ControlsWithoutIDs="DontPersist"></DBWC:DynamicControlsPlaceholder>
            <asp:Literal ID="LiteralJS" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Label ID="ccrTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CalendarUpdateBtn" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SubmitBtn" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ClearBtn" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


<!--/div-->
</form>
```

Much thanks!

Comment: Check out PerlNET - http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlNET_overview.html

Comment: Thanks JMK for the tip. I have looked over PerlNET and am unsure if this will work for what I need. I am attempting just a simple link to .NET and that is not working. I was hoping that would in which I believe I could have the Perl script call a C# function to send the message back to the webpage, but I can't get Perl to work with .NET let alone import my C# DLL and call its function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Im sorry I dont, I've only recently started learning Perl myself, hopefully somebody else will =)

Comment: I have learned now that PerlNET is a part of the ActiveState Perl Development Kit (PDK), which I do not have. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Perl needs to 'talk back' to the C# process, my suggestion would be to use a messaging protocol that will work well between Perl and C#.

Stomp - http://stomp.github.io/ would be one option - using ApacheNMS on the C# side and Net::Stomp on the Perl side, and a Stomp server in the middle.

ZeroMQ might be worth a look - http://www.zeromq.org/ - it might simplify things in that you won't need a separate broker process.

AMQP - http://www.amqp.org/ would be a third option.

And of course another good way to get Perl to talk back to C# is to set up a web service in your C# code and get Perl to call that using Mojo::UserAgent  https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent or similar.

Comment: We actually used ZeroMQ for another project and it is very fast and friendly. I'll be hopefully adding it to his project now that I've seen it in use. Thanks for information.